# Page Not Found 404 Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

So, i want to change page but i cant, as you can see in the image, I have the routes correct (i think) but still, when i try to go to that papge i get error 404 page not found!

The only route thats working its the Welcome blade route, the auth route are not working ass well i dont know why.

I already tried "php artisan clean:routes" code on cmd!

Can someon Help me

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0o0v.png)

Comment: What url you call ?

Comment: @Saromase i am calling the "AboutUs" (http://localhost/projeto/Health/public/AboutUs)

Comment: And in localhost/AboutUs ? it's work ?

Comment: It didint work. The weird thing is that the default auth routes that come with the "php artisan make:auth" code dont work either

Comment: Welcome! Please update the question to include the code in proper format. Do not use screenshots of code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://baseurl/AboutUs
```

This address should work properly, enter the desired local host or port address instead of baseurl, there is no problem in the code In php artisan serve

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks!

Comment: vote Remember :)